# NextJS + Redux Saga + SSR

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, next.js

we have a project, with a nextjs, redux saga, typescript setup.
SSR is very important for our web app, but we also have a lot of relevant widgets on every page.

This is why our page is structured in a modular way, where every widget (1-2 per page) loads the data it needs.
These widgets are relevant for SEO reasons now.

My problem is, that the API requests are not made on the serverside though. Right now it only returns the defaultState of every widget on the server and only loads them on the client.

I have searched and found a lot of instructions on how to do it, but they all rely on the fact that nextjs waits for the "getInitialProps" method until it returns the result from the server.
Since that lifecycle method is only available in the "pages" folder, that doesn't work for me.

Also if I block the "getInitialProps" component, the component is never really rendered.

Our pages are structured like below:

```
- pages/Home
    - <HomeContainer ...> (fetches data for the main page)
        - <HomeComponent >
            - <Widget1Container ...> (fetches data)
            - <Widget2Container ...> (fetches data)
```

What I want is for the serverside to wait for all the requests provided, before it returns the page to the user.
Because of the complex nature of different widgets on a page, it is not possible to create "combined" endpoint where we get the data in the "pages/Home" folder.

I know it's not ideal, but how could we make sure that the server actually makes all 3 requests (homecontainer, widget1container, widget2container) and awaits there responses, before returning?
I would like to have it like angular-universal does it. Just wait until there are not open requests or promises and then just render.
Any ideas?

Any help or ideas are deeply appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

since you are redux sage, in getServerSideProps, send the start signal to saga

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  async (context) => {

  store.dispatch(
    fetchWidgetsStart("add payload")
);
store.dispatch(END);
await (store as SagaStore).sagaTask.toPromise();
const state = store.getState();
// I am making up the reducer name
const widgetListState = state.widgetsList ? state.widgetList : null;
return { props: { productListState } };
```

}
);

inside saga function:

```
export function* fetchWidgetsStart() {
  yield takeLatest(
    WidgetListActionTypes.WIDGET_LIST_START,
    fetchWidgetssAsync
  );
}

function* fetchWidgetsAsync(action: IFetchWidgetssStart) {
  try {
    const res: AxiosResponse<IWidget[] | []> = Promise.all([
         yield axios.get(fetchWidget1),
         yield axios.get(fetchWidget2),
         yield axios.get(fetchWidget3)
     ])

    yield put(fetchWidgetSuccess(res));
    
  } catch (e: any) {
    
    yield put(
      fetchWidgetFailure(
        e.response && e.response.data.detail
          ? e.response.data.detail
          : e.message
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The Promise.all() method takes an iterable of promises as an input, and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises. This returned promise will resolve when all of the input's promises have resolved, or if the input iterable contains no promises. It rejects immediately upon any of the input promises rejecting or non-promises throwing an error, and will reject with this first rejection message / error.